# App works on emulator but crashes on real phone

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I created an application in android studio, the strange part is that the application works perfectly on the emulator, but when I press a certain button, the application crashes on the real phone.

Logcat:

> E/BufferQueueProducer: Unable to open libpenguin.so: dlopen failed: library "libpenguin.so" not found.
> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you please share the build.gradle file?

Comment: I see the same issue. The app seems to run, but with this error message. There's a [Closed issue](https://github.com/koreader/koreader/issues/9891) which has a link to this [Open issue](https://github.com/koreader/koreader/issues/9867).

Comment: @Bob please don't use links to resources that no longer exist. If you need an answer to your question, helpers should be able to reach all the information you provide. The link to build.gradle no longer works.